BeautifulSoup type error NoneType has no attribute text
This is the error
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-09a7a672688e> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 
     13 # Extract the app name
---> 14 app_name = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'AHFaub'}).text.strip()
     15 
     16 # Extract the app rating

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

This is the code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of the Hotstar app on the Google Play Store
url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.startv.hotstar'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Extract the app name
app_name = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'AHFaub'}).text.strip()

# Extract the app rating
app_rating = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'BHMmbe'}).text.strip()

# Extract other relevant data as needed...

# Print the extracted data
print('App Name:', app_name)
print('App Rating:', app_rating)


'NoneType' object has no attribute always means something is None and you try to access it, assuming it's not None. In your case soup.find did not find what you were looking for and returned None. Either use a debugger or add print(...)s to show what HTML you got. Maybe your class names are off. Maybe you got an error page.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

soup.find could not find a matching element, so it returned None. If you can't rely on always finding a matching element in your case, you should verify that you found an element before attempting to get the .text attribute.
# Extract the app name
app_el = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class': 'AHFaub'})
if app_el is None:
    # you probably don't want to just raise an error here
    # instead, handle the missing element however makes sense for your case
    raise ValueError('Failed to find a suitable element')
app_name = app_el.text.strip()

